# How ot Generate a series of Outlook appointment with irregular recurrence?

Tags: vba, outlook

For example, a meeting is to be held on the 23rd of every month. But if that day on 23rd is a Sunday, then the meeting will be put off to 24th. How can I genertate a single appointment series that contain all the dates above that can be sent to others in an single email using VBA macro? I heard you can use "exception" to move a single appointment in a recurrent series, how can this be realized? I will greatly appreciate any inputs :D

Answer (score 0):

Create a monthly recurring meeting and then modify the particular occurrences appropriately - Use AppointmentItem.GetReccurrencePattern, call RecurrencePattern.GetOccurrence, then modify the AppointmeentItem representing that occurrence appropriately.